# PHP 7.0 - HTTP_REFERER only contains domain name

Tags: php, apache

I need to check the referrer of a page that has an iframe pointing to our web site

apparently it only contains the domain name, not the whole url of the mother page

I have no idea if it's a php setting or apache setting, I cannot find any info about this

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!=""))
    $referrer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

it only contains

```
https://www.somedomain.com/
```

without the extra path

```
https://www.somedomain.com/path/parameter
```

how can I solve this ?

regads

Comment: A referer is fundamentally optional and unreliable…

Comment: Just FYI, HTTP REFERRER is set in the HTTP headers of the requesting client.  Therefore it's essentially user-input and cannot be depended on to be accurate.  If you think the value being presented in PHP is wrong then you might want to check what request is actually being made, especially with regards to the raw HTTP headers.  If the referrer header doesn't match what's being presented in PHP then that's where the problem lies, but I suspect that PHP is simply reporting what the headers say.

Comment: When you say "apparently", have you actually tried this? Because `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` definitely contains the full URL of the referring page. By default, anyway - it can always be spoofed.

Comment: yes, It only contains the fqdn while the mother page has the whole url...also I have no choice, the customer wants us to check the referrer and I know it's not a clever idea :-)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing the same thing - for every request.